# Time trial improvement from new bike

Tags: training, racing, weight, racing-bikes

I can average 21.7mph for a 20 mile time trial (00:55:15), on my 2001 Rockhopper with 1.25" fatboy slicks, no lock out on shock. My bike weighs 25.25 lbs. I'm planning on buying a Cervelo 2012 r3, 16.4 lbs estimated weight. I also plan on dropping 4-6 lbs, so my total weight would be about 14 pounds less. Does anyone have any idea what my average speed would be for a 20 mile time trial in good conditions, 10 mph max wind?

Comment: This completely depends on the route - how hilly is it? Are there a lot of sharp turns that'll make you slow down then accelerate back up to speed?

Comment: JEFROMI  The course i plan on doing in MAY 2013 is flat, 10mls down 10mls back. Wind is normaly 5-15 mph.  THANKS.

Comment: The R3 has several advantages over the Rockhopper:  No shocks, aero position, narrower tires, and lower weight.  Their significance is probably in that order.  Gaining 3 mph or so would be reasonable to expect.

Comment: Daniel,  I would be content if i can avg 24.0mph over the 20mls tt, This yes the speeds where between 17.5-27.0mph, the cyclist agv 23mph+ where all on TT bikes. 24.0 mph would have placed me 1st on regular ROAD BIKE, thats my goal. THANKS. JCF.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to play around with [Bike Calculator](http://bikecalculator.com) a little, and you could find a reasonable estimate for your question.

Regarding the new bike purchase, shop around carefully. You're already past what is considered the clearance season for 2012 models at many traditional brick-and-mortar bicycle retailers. Prime time is August/September of each year. That's when many retailers start their clearance sales.

Comment: ZIPPY,   Looks like 24.0mph est, in 3 differnt handle bar positions. A CERVELO P3 would really make an impact, but i can't afford 2 bikes. A R3 would be my choice for  all around road bike.  THANK YOU